# How to avoid JQuery UI accordion with a long table inside from scrolling to the beginning when new rows are appended?

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, accordion

I have a table of many rows in a JQuery UI accordion.

I dynamically append the table this way:

```
var resJson = JSON.parse(connector.process(JSON.stringify(reqJson)));
    for ( var i in resJson.entryArrayM) {
        // test if entry has already been displayed
        if ($("#resultTr_" + resJson.entryArrayM[i].id) == null)
            continue;
        $("#resultTable > tbody:last").append(listEntry.buildEntryRow(resJson.entryArrayM[i]));
    }
```

Firstly I check if a row of the same tr id already exists. If not, I would append to the last row of the table.

It works. But the problem is: every time a row is appended, the accordion would scroll to the first row of the table. Since the table is remarkably long, it makes users inconvenient to scroll down again and again to watch newly-added rows. So how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, just do one `append` rather than appending every time through the loop:

```
var resJson = JSON.parse(connector.process(JSON.stringify(reqJson)));
var seen    = { };
var rows    = [ ];
var trId    = null;
for(var i in resJson.entryArrayM) {
    // test if entry has already been displayed
    var trId = 'resultTr_' + resJson.entryArrayM[i].id;
    if($('#' + trId).length != 0
    || seen[trId])
        continue;
    rows.push(listEntry.buildEntryRow(resJson.entryArrayM[i]));
    seen[trId] = true;
}
$("#resultTable > tbody:last").append(rows.join(''));
```

Also note that I corrected your existence test, `$(x)` returns an empty object when `x` doesn't match anything, not `null`. Not only is this a lot more efficient but you'll only have one scroll position change to deal with.

Solving your scrolling issue is fairly simple: find out what element is scrolling, store its `scrollTop` before your append, and reset its `scrollTop` after the append:

```
var $el       = $('#whatever-is-scrolling');
var scrollTop = $el[0].scrollTop;
$("#resultTable > tbody:last").append(rows.join('')); // As above.
$el[0].scrollTop = scrollTop;
```

There might be a slight visible flicker but hopefully that will be lost in the noise of altering the table.

You could also try setting the [`table-layout` CSS property of the `<table>` to `fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout). That will keep the table from trying to resize its width or the width of its columns and that might stop the scrolling behavior that you're seeing. The downside is that you'll have to handle the column sizing yourself. But, you could try setting `table-layout:fixed` immediately before your `append` operation to minimize the hassle.